# How to get one column of mysql_query results into an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm selecting a single column from a MySQL table with `mysql_query()`. Is there already a function for getting the results into an array, or will I have to iterate through all the results with something like `mysql_fetch_array()`?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` returns an array itself. you can set array to be an associative or numeric. `array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )`

Comment: @UdaySawant I want a column, not a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate.

If you moved into the 21st century, and used mysqli, there's a [mysqli_fetch_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) function.... and you'd be able to use prepared statements

Comment: Now if you moved right into the 22nd century and used PDO... ;o)

Comment: @deceze - I edited it.... originally I'd said 20th century, with a comment about PDO.... but decided that 1 step at a time might be kinder on the OP's sanity

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with mysqli_fetch_all and array_column

```
$r = mysqli_query($c,"SELECT bug_name FROM bugs WHERE color='red'");
$bug_names = array_column(mysqli_fetch_all($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC),"bug_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like that built in, you will need to do this manually.

Answer (score -1):

you can use mysql_result function still need to do some coding

```
mysql_result($result,$row_num,$fieldname) ;
```

retrieves $row_num 'th columes  $field_name field .

and following snippet can be taken as an example

```
$con =mysql_connect($host,$uname,$passwd);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$con);
$result = mysql_query($query,$con);
$arr = array();
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for($i=0;$i<$numrows;$i++) {
    $arr[] = mysql_result($result,$i,$fieldname);
}
```

this stores every elements of column $fieldname to 
array $arr

Comment: I wanted to avoid that iterating, though.